# @media screen units are not pixels, so what are they?

Tags: css

This is what I want

If browser is bigger than 900px I want the boxes to be 700px.
Once the browser width is smaller than 900px I want the boxes to be 600px.

```
@media screen and (min-width : 750px) and (max-width : 900px) {
    .multiSelect .checkboxLayer {
        width: 600px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .multiSelect .checkboxLayer {
        width: 700px;
    }
}
```

My question is, how come the browser width splits around 932px and not 900px?
What units are these if not pixels?

[image]

I just tried to measure the browser width with photoshop and it splits at 975 px exactly.

So CSS says 900 px, Chrome says 932 px and photoshop says 975 px
This is really confusing?!?!

Comment: You are required to show a minimal but complete example of the markup that shows the problem: [mcve]

Comment: Hi Rob - Normally I would, but the CSS used to construct `.multiSelect .checkboxLayer`  is massive, its too much to post here.  But I will try and see if I can make a simpler example thats easier to run and debug for others.

Comment: It's the only way we can help. Otherwise it's all a wild guess.

Comment: Is the difference maybe because of different width scroll bars in the different browser?

Comment: Just did the simpler example, and of cause it works just fine hehe - at least now I have an idea where it might be :)

Comment: Yes definitely one of the reasons are different scrollbars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer:**

You have not reset the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property for the parent container.

---

**The long answer:**

Consider this:

> In CSS, by default, the width and height you assign to an element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen.

There are two values in `box-sizing` that you should know about

1. **content-box**

   > [...] the default, and gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If you
   >   set an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content box
   >   will be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding will
   >   be added to the final rendered width.
2. **border-box**

   > [...] tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the
   >   value you specify for width and height. If you set an element's width
   >   to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you
   >   added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width.
   >   This typically makes it much easier to size elements.

I usually start any CSS sheet with the following to avoid such issues

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

There are many frameworks that reset more of the default properties such as [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) but I often don't have the need to use them.

---

I set up a demo below. There are two `div` elements. There is also a media query.

Both elements have the same **fixed** `width` in `px`. The only difference is the value for the `box-sizing`

The first is set to `border-box` and the second is set to `content-box`

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background: darkred;
  border: 20px solid #131418
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  div {
    background: darkgreen;
    width: 300px;
  }
}

.first {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.second {
  box-sizing: content-box
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Notice how they render with different sizes even when the `width` for both is the same?

Comment: I didnt know that!! - very interesting - Thanks for teaching me something new Coder Cat :-)

Comment: No problem @torbenrudgaard I'm happy to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bar width is 17px on most browsers, and does not contribute to the screen width. Try using Firefox's responsive design mode, in the dev tools.

Comment: I have no clue how this answers the question in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @Rob Imagine you've never seen a boat before, but one day you're standing on the shore and one is floating off in the distance - you ask your buddy "Have you ever seen a whale like that before?" He tells you "Boats are used to float on water." - Did he answer your question?

Comment: Your comment is no more help than your answer. Imagine someone coming to this question one year from now with the same question looking for an answer.

Comment: Although language is not meant to be relative, communicated ideas are received through a lens of perception and previously assimilated concepts. You're right, this state of mind is likely a rare one, but in this particular case it seems to have been a successful exchange.